# How to reuse the new Biology.SE Logo on personal websites?

Tags: support

I would like to use the new Biology.SE logo on my website.

- How can I get an image of this logo on a neutral background?
- Is there an [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)-like icon of the Biology.SE logo?

*EDIT - in reaction to comment and current answer*

I am aiming to use this logo as on my website as a link to my Biology.SE profile. Many people use the Twitter logo to link their Twitter profile on the their website. My aim is similar. Note that [academicons](https://github.com/jpswalsh/academicons) already has a StockOverflow icon (font-awesome like icon). I am looking for something similar for the Biology.SE icon.

Of course, if this still sounds like not a fair use of the Biology.SE logo, then I won't use the logo.

Comment: can you do that legally ? I mean trademark and all that?

Comment: I would be surprised if this wasn't ok (fair use), especially since the whole point of e.g. [flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/2339529/remi-b?tab=flair) is to put it on personal webpages (and the flair includes a small version of the logo).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to keep in mind that the logo is a trademark and Stack Exchange has the copyright on it. [See the Stack Exchange trademark guidelines for more information about it](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> The logos associated with Stack Exchange Inc. and any Stack Exchange
>   site are a trademark. The purpose of trademark law is to prevent
>   consumers from being misled as to the origin of a product. So if you
>   were making a product, and you used a Stack Exchange name or logo in
>   your product (or in its advertising) in such a way that would mislead
>   someone into thinking that your product was owned by, operated by,
>   endorsed by, or in any way part of Stack Exchange Inc., you would be
>   violating the trademark and this would not be legal.
>
> Our logo images and site names are copyrighted. Any content on the
>   Stack Exchange Network not contributed by users is copyrighted.
>   Copyright is different than trademark. Ordinarily you couldn't copy
>   it. But if you were writing a news story or blog post about a Stack
>   Exchange site, reproducing the logo image would almost certainly be
>   considered "fair use" and allowed under trademark law because you were
>   not using it "in trade."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it makes sense. I wanted to use the logo to link to my Biology.SE profile on my website. In a similar way, people use the Twitter logo on their website to link to their Twitter account. Note that on [academicons](https://github.com/jpswalsh/academicons), there is a font-awesome -like icon for StackOverflow. This site would probably benefit from allowing people to reuse their logos to link to their SE profile (sounds like "fair use"). Am I getting it right?

Comment: I must confess that I "pocket down voted" your answer with my phone but I just noticed and it's too late to take it back. Sorry!

Comment: @canadianer I have now provided the yin to your yang.

Comment: @fileunderwater You complete me.